# two values in a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

Basically what Im trying to do is have an array of events and in it will hold the title and date.. So what i have so far is a wordpress loop of a custom post type pulling in the title and the date set..

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'events', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => ASC);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

$events = array();
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); //START LOOP

    $title = get_the_title();
    $dateAndTime = get_field('date_and_time_of_event');

endwhile; //END LOOP

wp_reset_postdata();
```

And i want to set it up like this

```
Array (
   [title] => array(
                  [0] => Event1
                  [1] => Event2
              )
   [date] => array(
                  [0] => 12/12/13
                  [1] => 10/11/13
              )
)
```

Im trying to push a bunch of values that im pulling in from a loop to a multidimensional array and cant quite figure it out.
Im new too this and would like some help, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$titles = $dates = array();

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); //START LOOP

$titles[] = get_the_title();
$dates[] = get_field('date_and_time_of_event');

endwhile; //END LOOP

$result = array('title' => $titles, 'date' => $dates);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result['title'][] = get_the_title();
$result['date'][]  = get_field('date_and_time_of_event');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$data = array();
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); //START LOOP

$data['title'][] = get_the_title();
$data['date'][] = get_field('date_and_time_of_event');

endwhile; //END LOOP
```

This way you'll have an array like the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

For your array, wouldn't it be better to have it set up as such:

```
Array   (   [0] => array(   [title] => Event1,
                            [date]  => 12/12/13),
            [1] => array(   [title] => Event2,
                            [date]  => 10/11/13)
        )
```